# Is there a way to initialise an array using an expression/function in R

Tags: arrays, r, function, initialization, expression

Is there an easy way to initialise an array using a function based on the indexes of each cell within the array?

For example if I wanted to create an array with values equal to i+j+k such that (for example):

```
> A[1,2,3]
   6 
> A[4,8,9]
   21
```

I'd like something along the lines of:

`A <- array( i+j+k  , dim=c(10,10,10) , dimnames=list(i,j,k) )`

Do I first need to create an array of the size I want, and then apply a function to that array (ie a two-stage process)? Or is there a way to initilize all the values at the same time as creating the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Nested `outer` calls seem to do the trick (here just up to 3 for visibility):

```
 outer(outer(1:3,1:3,"+"),1:3,"+")
```

Or to duplicate your example:

```
> A=outer(outer(1:10,1:10,"+"),1:10,"+")
> A[1,2,3]
[1] 6
> A[4,8,9]
[1] 21
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using `expand.grid`

```
v1 <- 1:10
l <- length(v1)
n <- 3
A <- array(rowSums(expand.grid(rep(list(v1), n))), dim= rep(l, n))
A[1, 2, 3]
#[1] 6
A[4, 8, 9]
#[1] 21
```